# Hook_menu_alter not working?

Tags: hooks, routes

```
**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/

define('RATE_PATH_RESULTS_PAGE', 'node/%node/rating');

function rate_menu() {
  $menu = array();

   $menu[RATE_PATH_RESULTS_PAGE] = array(
     'title' => 'Voting results',
     'page callback' => 'rate_results_page',
     'page arguments' => array(1),
     'access callback' => 'rate_results_page_access',
     'access arguments' => array('view rate results page', 1),
     'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
     'weight' => 10,
    'file' => 'rate.results.inc',
);

  return $menu;
}
```

Above menu item comes from rate module, I want to override permission of this menu item. For now permissions are defined for user roles from permissions page. But according to my requirement I want this menu link visible to users on nodes only when user is author of node. Due to this I want to take control of this menu item in my custom module.

```
function custom_menu_alter(&$menu){
  $menu[RATE_PATH_RESULTS_PAGE] = array(
    'title' => 'Voting results page',
 );

}
```

I am trying by writing above function for alter menu in my custom module. Please guid me with proper way, what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: An empty alter function will never do anything, can you edit the actual code you're using into the question and describe what it's doing/not doing/what you expect it to do?

Comment: sorry I updated question now

Comment: I just tried by changing title but nothing changes and my previous working menu also disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the whole item with this:

```
$menu[RATE_PATH_RESULTS_PAGE] = array(
  'title' => 'Voting results page',
);
```

Which clears out the page callback, access callback, and so on.

Instead, you want to replace the individual relevant components like this:

```
$menu[RATE_PATH_RESULTS_PAGE]['title'] = 'Voting results page';
```

Comment: Thanks ! now in similar way I can change function to be used for access callback.